# How to get non-negative value using Do until or if statement?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a polynomial equation that i want to solve: L^3-4043L-60647=0 using goal seek in the vba. 
This equation gives 3 roots : L1=70.06, L2, -54.04 and L3=-16.02 according to my calculator. But i only want my L in my excel cell to show the first positive root as my answer. 
However when i do the goalseek using vba, it only gives me -16.02. How do i tell in my code to only solve for positive value?

I already tried using Do until and if statement. However Do until statement kept crashing and If statement is giving me wrong values.

```vb
Sub GoalSeek()

 'GoalSeek Macro
Dim Length As Double
Dim i As Long
Range("Length") = i

If i > 0 Then

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("GS").GoalSeek Goal:=0.1, ChangingCell:=Range("Length")

Else

End If
End Sub
```

I tried using this if statement. However my L or "Length" comes up only to be 0. I am very very beginner level in VBA. I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

GoalSeek gets the nearest solutions to the starting value.

You can use the following code:

```
Sub GoalSeek()
    Dim i As Double
    'Set the initial value to a very high number
    Range("Result").Value = 9999
    'Ask GoalSeek to get the neares solution to that high value
    Range("Formula").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("Result")
    If Range("Result").Value > 0 Then 
    'If the value is positive, we need to make sure that it is the first positive solution
        i = -1
        Do
            i = i + 1
            'Set a new inital value. This time, a small one (starting from 0)
            Range("Result").Value = i
            'Ask GoalSeek to get the neares solution to the small initial value
            Range("Formula").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("Result")
        'If the result is negative, loop (increase the initial value and try again till you find the first positive one
        Loop While Range("Result").Value < 0
    Else 'If the nearest result to the high value is negative, keep it & show a message box.
        MsgBox "No +ve solution found"
    End If
End Sub
```

In your example, you have three solutions 70.06, -54.04 & -16.02

The nearest to 0 is -16.02, to 9999 is 70.6 and to -9999 is -54.04

What if the solutions are -5, 7 & 12?

The nearest to 9999 is 12, but you want 7, right?

So we ask for the nearest to 0 (-5) then, we keep increasing the initial value till the nearest solution becomes 7.

**Please note that this assumes that you have an idea about what the results would be.**

For example, if the solutions are -1 & 1,000,000, this code will not work because -1 is nearer to 9999 than 1,000,000.

In this case, you will need to change the initial high value more.

**AND** if you set it to a too high value that exceeds the limit of double data type 1.79E+308 or even to a value that makes the result of the formula exceed it, you will get an error.